# How to make the variable price - 500, formed not as a curve, but as a horizontal line with coordinates (price - 500)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[Demonstration of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6piP.png)

I don't know how to get the horizontal line when using the calculations for the variable. Please see the attached picture.Moreover, it is the variable that is needed, and not the output of data through the plot function.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="intersection", shorttitle="INTR",overlay = true, max_bars_back = 100)

a = 44626
plot(a, '1', color = color.white)
//How can I make it so that during calculations I get not a curve but a horizontal line? those. when calculating the output, not the curve a1, but a.
a1 = close - 1000
plot(a1, '1', color = color.red)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question. Your red line is defined by `close - 1000`. It cannot be horizontal. It depends on the close price.

Comment: Yes, that's right, so I can't draw a horizontal line from the price difference and 1000.I'm trying to get a horizontal line based on the closing price (price -1000) and then using the functions isCond21 = ta.crossunder(close, a)
isCond11 = ta.crossover(close, a)
isCond1 = ta.cross(a, close). The loop for..... to , is too slow and gentle)))), and this will allow you to bypass it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to do that. Using an `hline` or a `line.new`

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="intersection", shorttitle="INTR",overlay = true, max_bars_back = 100)

a = 44626
plot(a, '1', color = color.blue)
//How can I make it so that during calculations I get not a curve but a horizontal line? those. when calculating the output, not the curve a1, but a.
a1 = close - 1000
plot(a1, '1', color = color.red)
// hline way
hline(a,'A HLine', color.blue)
//line.new way
if barstate.islast
    line.new(bar_index, a1, bar_index + 1, a1, extend = extend.both)
```